# Is it possible to find a homomorphism between sound frequencies and light frequencies?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would like to find some mapping from audible sound to visible light.

The audible sounds are represented by a frequency (Hz) and the name of a note (C0 .. C10). For example, A4 can be defined as 440Hz. If A4 is noted at $i = 0$, then the frequency of any given note is

$ \lambda = 440 Hz * 2^{(i / 12)} $

The visible spectrum can also be represented by frequency (eg. red is about 400 - 484 THz).

---

How do I find a homomorphism between these two spaces?

(A caveat, maybe as an afterthought, is that the notes A0, A1, A2, all sound relatively similar. They are simply an octave apart. Is there a way to produce a mapping such that any note an octave apart maps to a similar color, ie. their light frequencies are close?)

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information or clarification. I'm unsure of what else to include, so I left it as is for now.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're looking for. Audible sound falls within some frequency range, and visible light, another. Why not just map the one interval into the other? If you do this, you should have more than just a homomorphism - I think since you'd just be stretching the interval by some factor, you'd have isomorphism.

Edit: if you're trying to get notes an octave apart to have the same color, try looking into the wrapping function. https://learnzillion.com/lessons/2771-understand-the-wrapping-function-using-the-unit-circle

Comment: I think that's what I'm confused about. How would I find the function to convert audio to visual? EDIT: Posted at the same time - thank you for the link. I think my question remains, though.

Comment: You need to scale the length of the interval by the appropriate factor, and translate. I don't know the intervals in question, but if you wanted to map [0,1] into [1,4], you would note that the former has length 1, and the latter length 3. So you would define the function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [1,4]$ by $f(x)=3x+1$

Comment: @AlfredYerger Ah, I see - that makes sense. So it's done, basically, "manually"? I don't know why I thought there would be an automatic process for finding the function?

Comment: I think that besides the mathematical problem, which has already been answered, there's a conceptual problem. Even if sound and light are both oscillatory phenomena it doesn't mean they are oscillations of the same thing. Sound is an oscillation in the air pressure while light is an oscillation of the electromagnetic field. 

Also, while our ears can detect some periodicity in the sounds we hear, for example we know La corresponds to 110 Hz, 220 Hz, 440 Hz,... (1/2)

Comment: Such thing doesn't happen with our eyes. This is because if you take an integer multiple (or take the half, third,...) of any frequency in the visible spectrum you'll end up with a frequency which isn't visible. (2/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapping between two intervals is not hard.  I won't pick frequencies, so if the audio spectrum is $[AL,AH]$ and the  visible spectrum is $[VL,VH]$ a linear transformation from audio to visible is $x \to \frac {VH-VL}{AH-AL}(x-AL)+VL$  This does not consider your thought that all the $A$'s sound similar.  As one without [absolute pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_pitch) I don't understand the idea that all the $A$'s are similar, but maybe others do.  That introduces a structure to the audio space that does not exist in the visible space, so you should not expect a correspondence that respects that.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful. There does seem to be a structure in the visual space - that is of proximity.

Comment: When you talk of visual space, you may be thinking of $R,G,B$ space, which is very different from the visible spectrum.  The visible spectrum is all pure frequencies like pure musical tones.  There are many colors not represented in the visible spectrum.  In a sense they correspond to chords in audio space, as they represent mixes of frequencies.  However, we don't react to color the same way as we do to audio-simple ratios don't have the same force in the video spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to find a map which respects the octave equivalence, you will need to abandon the idea of mapping pitches to *pure* light frequencies (since light has no similar concept of "far away colors which sound like each other"). You could draw a closed curve in [chromaticity space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity), and map every A to the same point on that curve; alternately, if you wanted to make A440 and A880 sound similar, but not identical, you could draw a spiral in that space...